# Arduino I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE

Tags: arduino, warnings

I am using the I2Cdevlib for an Arduino project. I have activated the compilation verbose and get this warning:

```
I2Cdev.cpp:64:14: warning: #warning Using current Arduino IDE with Wire library is functionally limiting.
I2Cdev.cpp:65:14: warning: #warning Arduino IDE v1.0.1+ with I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE implementation is recommended.
I2Cdev.cpp:66:14: warning: #warning This I2Cdev implementation does not support:
I2Cdev.cpp:67:14: warning: #warning - Timeout detection (some Wire requests block forever)
```

I don't understand what this Arduino version is/where I can find it. My projects blocks after a few minutes, it consists of permanantly reading the data from a gyroscope. So I though that this warning could give me a hint on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I2C originally is defined without a time-out. More recent derivative of I2C (like SMBus) added the possibility for a device to time-out (usually after 10 - 50 ms). If a device with time-out is connected to a device without time-out and the communication is very slow, they may come out of sync and hang.

Answer (score 1):

I found I2CdevLib for Arduino and the latest version seems to be corrected about this.
The source code can be found here :
https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/I2Cdev/I2Cdev.cpp

Updating your I2CdevLib should solve the problem.(Have you downloaded it or was it delivered with your Arduino IDE ?)

If your Arduino IDE version is less than 1.6.x you should update too.